# How to change initialValue dynamically inside getfielddecorator antd?

Tags: reactjs, styles, antd

I want to change initial value of select when ever user selects option.

To be more precise, I have many options to select and by default I want display "All" and whenever user selects another option(s) "All" option should disappear.

What I have done : I have tried to render initialValue conitionally whenever user selects option

```
      <Form.Item label="Компьютеры">
        {getFieldDecorator("computers", {
          initialValue: this.props.status ? null : "All",

        })(
          <Select
            mode="multiple"
            onChange={this.handleCompChange}
          >
            {this.props.comps.map(comp => (
              <Option value={comp.key} key={comp.key}>
                {comp.name}
              </Option>
            ))}
          </Select>
        )}
      </Form.Item>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't dynamically change the `initialValue` unless your unmount the `Form.Item`.

Comment: if you understand thing which I want

Comment: You wan't to have 'All' tag selected, and on user select to remove it?

Comment: Its a bad practice, you should use a placeholder

Comment: It is requirement ( by customer

Comment: I figure out it is too complicated to do in uncontrolled form, you either need to use `onValuesChange` or add a condition to unmount the form item